# Adjective to describe office functionary who consistently, unknowingly refers paperwork to the wrong department?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a single-word adjective to describe an office functionary who consistently incorrectly refers paperwork onwards to the wrong internal department in his or her organisation because he or she doesn't realise he or she is wrong?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to be picky but this is a [tag:single-word-request], so not only does it require the tag, but an exemplary sentence (see the tag details) where you might use it, or it may be closed. We also have a research requirement. I suggest mentioning why [bureaucratic](http://tinyurl.com/h9q4mqj) and [its closest synonyms in a thesaurus don't work](http://tinyurl.com/zcv7wk3). You can read more about our bureaucratic policies in the [help center](http://tinyurl.com/jlol7sj), esp. the parts regarding what you [may](http://tinyurl.com/glmbv5y) or [may not](http://tinyurl.com/hdo3t4y) ask us.

Comment: This question seems under-constrained. In an office environment, surely someone would tell the person that they sent things to the wrong place. Why are they still ignorant of this? The reason will likely narrow the choice of adjective. Please [edit] to constrain the question further. I'll vote to place this question on hold for being too broad. Please feel free to contact me about reversing my vote after you have edited. (Just post a comment containing "@Lawrence".)

Comment: I would say "incompetent" or "careless".

Comment: Like most new SE users? We're always getting questions that should have been referred to someone else.

Comment: Please do not create the example sentence if you are not the person who needs the word.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that such an "office functionary*" is either ***untrained***, or, if they have been trained and maybe even retrained, ***incompetent***.

Answer (score 0):

This would be (wilfully) [***ignorant***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ignorant).

> ADJECTIVE
>   1 Lacking knowledge or awareness; uneducated or unsophisticated.
>   *‘In that way, our people can remain ignorant, uneducated and dumb.’*

Reference:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ignorant

===

Edit (added definition of *willfully ignorant* from **Wiktionary**):

> **[willful ignorance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/willful_ignorance)** ‎(uncountable)
>
> (idiomatic, law) A decision in bad faith to avoid becoming informed
>   about something so as to avoid having to make undesirable decisions
>   that such information might prompt.

Comment: +1 for _wilfully_. Added a definition of _willful ignorance_ on your behalf.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve been given several functional words. 
Here are a few more colorful ones:

> ***[airhead](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/airhead):***
>
>   a mindless or stupid person
>
> ***[scatterbrained](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scatterbrained):***
>
>   having the characteristics of a scatterbrain
>
> ***[scatterbrain](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scatterbrain):***
>
>       a person who is unable
>         to concentrate or think clearly
>
> ***[clueless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clueless):***
>
>   not having knowledge about something : unable to understand something
>
> ***[confused](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confused):***
>
>   unable to understand or think clearly

***Bemused***, ***bewildered***, ***disoriented*** and ***flustered***
are the past participles of
***bemuse***, ***bewilder***, ***disorient*** and ***fluster***,
respectively; they are all approximately synonyms for ***confuse***
(so the ***-ed*** words are all approximately synonyms for ***confused***). 
Definitions are all from Merriam-Webster.

Comment: In the British context **waste of space** and **plonker** (mainly for a man) could be added to your list. In both British and American contexts **air-head** can be used (particularly for a woman).